# jQuery do not have scope in Marionette module

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I tried to create a Marionette module. When I access the template using jQuery in the module, it returns undefined. It happens for with or without default 6 arguments.

Note:
in the main.js this variable returns properly only in the module it returns undefined.

```
//App.module("LineModule", function(LineModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $){
App.module("LineModule", function(LineModule){

    console.log('LINE DRAFT : ' + $('#line-grid-content-template').html()); // undefined

});
```

What could be the reason? how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will normally happen if #line-grid-content-template has not yet been added to the DOM. A few places to first check are, make sure it has the right ID (it's not a class or a miss spelling) and also that who ever is responsible for rendering the div has rendered it before you try to access it via the jQuery selector.

Comment: Yes! That was the issue! JavaScript files are rendering through PHP in my code thats why it happened.